# Header and Footer XSL FO

Tags: header, footer, xsl-fo

I want to create a PDF document with a header and a footer in every pages, I don't know why they only appears in odd pages.

I simplify the code and I create a table and I repeated several times to have 4 pages but the result is the same, the header and footer appears only in the first and the third page.

Here is the code. The xsl version is 1.0.

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match ="template">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:layout-master-set>
<!-- layout information -->
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="pagetemplate"
              page-height="29.7cm"
              page-width="21cm"
              margin-top="1cm"
              margin-bottom="0.1cm"
              margin-left="0.8cm"
              margin-right="1.0cm">
  <fo:region-body margin-top="2.5cm" margin-bottom="2.5cm"/>
  <fo:region-before extent="2.0cm"/>
  <fo:region-after extent="2.0cm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="pagetemplate">

          <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
      <fo:block>
           <xsl:call-template name="header"/>
       </fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>

      <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
       <fo:block>
        <xsl:call-template name="footer"/>
       </fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>

      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

     <xsl:call-template name="block"/>
             <xsl:call-template name="block"/>
             <xsl:call-template name="block"/>
             <xsl:call-template name="block"/>

      </fo:flow>

</fo:page-sequence>

</fo:root>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem.

The thing was that the margins of region-body, region-before and region-after weren't correct.